# What does it mean by 'gcroot' in c++

Tags: c#, c++-cli

I am dealing with a c++ code which I have to convert to c#. And I am trying to understand the c++ code where it has this thing called "gcroot". According to my knowledge "gcroot" is a template. I have no clue about it more than that.

Could anyone please explain to me what 'gcroot' is and what does it do?

Also, What does a code like following would do?

```
  gcroot< TRANS_DB::GHT* > M_HAT;
```

Comment: First link in search is your answer - http://www.bing.com/search?q=gcroot - [How to: Declare Handles in Native Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/481fa11f.aspx)

Comment: no. it does not help..

Comment: Hmm, that dup certainly doesn't explain anything.  gcroot<> helps C++ code to keep a reference on a managed object so it doesn't get collected.  The underlying call is GCHandle.Alloc().  When you translate such code to C# then the need for this just disappears, a regular object reference works fine.

Comment: What does not help? If it is not managed C++ you should explicitly say so for this particular question.

Comment: @HansPassant - maybe you should edit question to "how to convert Managed C++ gcroot template to C#" and indeed it should be reopened than, right now to me it looks like "is there anything special about gcroot template in any C++ implementation"...